# Two questions regarding JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, return, settimeout

I have two questions regarding the following function. Obviously, it is about a chat. In the function `chat()` different functions are called, one to establish a connection, one to search for someone to chat with (randomly), and one to get messages every second.

```
function chat()
{
    //Open connection
    var openconnection=openConnection();
    //Stop function if connection could not be established
    if(openconnection==false) return;

    //Search for someone to chat with
    searchforcontact=searchForContact();
    if(searchforcontact==false) return;

    //Constantly get messages
    setTimeout(function(){
        setInterval(getMessages(),1000);
    },2000);
}

function openConnection() { 
    //Establish connection to php script 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'action/chat/openconnection.php', 
        success: function(connection) { 
            //Let user know that someone to chat with is searched for 
            $('#chatTextDiv').append('bla'); 
            //Return that the connection was successfull 
            return true; 
        } 
    }).error(function() { 
        //Let user know that a connection could not be established 
        $('#chatTextDiv').append('bla'); 
        //Return false 
        return false; 
    }); 
}
```

Here are my questions:

1: I use return to stop the function `chat()` if, e.g., a connection could not be established. However the functions goes on to `searchForContact()`, and even if that fails, still goes on. How come?

2: The function `getMessages()` only runs once, I wonder why? FYI, I use the timeout for usability.

Comment: 1) Can you post the sources of `openConnection`? 2) It has to be `setInterval(getMessages, 1000)`. Your code invokes `getMessages` and then sets the interval on whatever `getMessages` returns (probably no function?). BTW: `setTimeout` and `return` are independent of jQuery.

Comment: 1) I will post the code in a sec. 2) getMessages() is a function, still call in in setTimeout without parantheses?

Comment: function openConnection()
{
    //Establish connection to php script
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action/chat/openconnection.php',
        success: function(connection){

            //Let user know that someone to chat with is searched for
            $('#chatTextDiv').append('bla');

            //Return that the connection was successfull
            return true;
        }
    }).error(function(){
        //Let user know that a connection could not be established
        $('#chatTextDiv').append('bla');

        //Return false
        return false;
    });

Comment: You should really read up on how AJAX and asynchronous APIs work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `openConnection()` doesn't return false. Since synchronous API are very uncommon and not really useable from within JavaScript, I am pretty sure, that `openConnection` does not work the way you use it. Please provide more information on the `openConnection` function.

Also, instead of passing the `getMessages` function to the call to `setInterval`, you invoke `getMessages` and pass whatever it returns to `setInterval`. This is most likely not what you want. You should change that call to the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(getMessages,1000);
},2000);
```

You should really read up on how AJAX and asynchronous APIs in general work. To give you a head-start here is an update to your code that should demonstrate what you're doing wrong:

```
function openConnection(success, error) { 
    //Establish connection to php script 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'action/chat/openconnection.php', 
        success: success
    }).error(error||function () {}); 
}

function chat(ready) {
    //Open connection
    openConnection(function () {
        // If this function is called, then the connection is established

        //Search for someone to chat with
        searchforcontact=searchForContact();
        if(searchforcontact==false) return;

        // I STRONGLY SUPPOSE searchForContact is also an asynchronous API!

        //Constantly get messages
        setTimeout(function(){
            setInterval(getMessages,1000);
            ready();
        },2000);
    }, function () {
        // when this function is called, something went wrong.
    });
}

chat(function () {
    // when this function is called, chat is ready to be used!
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try that.

See openConnection() here:

function openConnection()
{
 //Establish connection to php script
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'action/chat/openconnection.php',
     success: function(connection){
      
   //Let user know that someone to chat with is searched for
   $('#chatTextDiv').append('bla');
   
   //Return that the connection was successfull
   return true;
     }
 }).error(function(){
  //Let user know that a connection could not be established
     $('#chatTextDiv').append('bla');
  
  //Return false
  return false;
 });
}

Comment: Please dont post code in comments, but update your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sorry for answering a question with a question, but what are the values of `openconnection` and `searchforcontact`? It appears that they are not satisfying the conditional, so your return statement is not running. You can verify the value with FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools.
2. `getMessages` runs only once because your invoking it instead of passing it to `setInterval`. It should be `setInterval(getMessages, 1000);`.

Comment: 1. When I alert both I get undefined, even when they should be false...
2. Thanks!

Comment: As @Daniel Baulig points out, you're misunderstanding how AJAX (The "A" stands for "Asynchronous") works. Your `openConnection` and `searchforcontact` methods are going to return immediately, and since you don't explicitly return a value, your vars are getting set to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks - should I maybe set the method to asynchronous then? I am aware that I will have to read into that though.